# How to hide a folder in published items

Tags: c#, winforms

In file property settings → `Copy To` - `Do Not Copy` - But that folder contains a data which is used in application. So I need it in `publish` but could not be accessed by client.

Comment: How will your app read it, if they cant see it?

Comment: Can you embed the data files from the folder in your application?

Comment: maybe you can encrypt data and keep the folder visible !

Comment: you can set in webconfig or in your IIS to don't allow access to your file/folder

Comment: webconfig or in your IIS are not applicable as this is winforms not web

Comment: Thanks all for your reply.. Kevorkian - As per your advice I encrypt the folder on publish.. On installation by client whether the data will get copied to bin or else I have to do a decryption there..

Answer (score 0):

Use Resources in Properties -> Resources. The client will not get access to the files, your application will.

Comment: Adding the file in resources and setting access modifier as internal.